# Make ordered numbers from intersections using GeoPandas

Tags: python, postgresql, geopandas

I'm have two shapefiles: points and line. What I want to do is to check
how many points are intersecting with/belonging to a single line feature, then I'd like to
order the points based on the line feature they belong to. The code I wrote  keeps making empty or wrong numbers. Any suggestion?

Here is my code:

```
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame()

for line in duct.geometry:
   line_length = line.length  

   # Intersect the line with the points
   line_points = points.intersection(line)

  # Iterate through the intersected points
   for i, p in enumerate(line_points, start=1):
       points = points.append({'number': i, 'geometry': p}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You should [Edit] the Question to provide data samples for testing, and  some diagnostic `print` statements to explain the issue you are encountering. Some points can never be "on" some lines due to floating-point precision issues, so you may need to locate the point of tangency for points which do not intersect.

Comment: Order them how? Can you add a screenshot or drawing?

Answer (score 1):

Even though they appear to intersect they probably dont.

I drew two lines and snapped six points to them in QGIS and they still dont intersect.

Try [sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html) instead to join by a distance.

```
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd

#Create two testdataframes
lines = [b'\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00,L\xf2b\x07\x87$A\xc9\xc8\x9f\xdf\x9f\x1cYA\xfb\xb71\xe4\x92\x8a$A\xe5\xca\xd6r\x04\x1cYA\nzw-\xf1\x8a$Ac\xfc\x0b\xdec\x1bYA\xcbT\x02\xe6\xba\x8f$A|A{Ih\x1bYA\xde\x1f\xe2\x01\xff\x90$A\xe5\x00Y\xc7\xd6\x1bYA7\xac\x84\xb94\x93$A\xa2\xdc+U&\x1cYA',
         b"\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00g\x0f\xb4\xb7\x0c\x8e$A\x19\r\x8c\x9d7\x1dYA\xd1\x04\x14\x8aM\x8e$Ao\xcb\x07\xab\x8f\x1cYA\x03\x85\x10\xb9\xea\x91$A\x8f'\x9c\x8f\x95\x1cYA"]

lines = [shapely.wkb.loads(x) for x in lines]

points = [b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\xd9\xd3!w\r\x88$AG\x8a\xff\xfcr\x1cYA',
          b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x93~\xb2\x91\xac\x89$A\xdb\xb2\x1f\xe5+\x1cYA',
          b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1e\xcfv|\xd2\x8a$A}\x1f\x81#\x98\x1bYA',
          b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\\\xb5/q-\x8d$A\x10\x7fJ\xeee\x1bYA',
          b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbe3@\xcc\xd8\x8f$A\xc3B\x87/\x92\x1cYA',
          b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00Q\xfb\xa4k\x1e\x8e$A:\x1e\xb3\xbf\t\x1dYA']

points = [shapely.wkb.loads(x) for x in points]

linedf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=lines, crs=3006)
linedf["lineid"] = range(linedf.shape[0])
pointdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=points, crs=3006)
pointdf["pointid"] = range(pointdf.shape[0])

#overlay intersection
intersection = gpd.overlay(linedf, pointdf, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=False)
print(intersection)
# Empty GeoDataFrame 
# Columns: [geometry]
# Index: []

#The first line and first point should intersect
print(linedf.iloc[0].geometry.intersects(pointdf.iloc[0].geometry))
#False

#What is their distance from eachother
print(linedf.iloc[0].geometry.distance(pointdf.iloc[0].geometry))
#1.462987681183726e-10
#0.14 nanometers apart

#Spatial join nearest instead
sj = gpd.sjoin_nearest(pointdf, linedf, how="inner", max_distance=0.1)
print(sj[["pointid", "lineid"]])
#    pointid  lineid
# 0        0       0
# 1        1       0
# 2        2       0
# 3        3       0
# 4        4       1
# 5        5       1
#Now all points are found

sj["pointnumber"] = sj.groupby("lineid").cumcount()+1
print(sj[["pointid", "lineid", "pointnumber"]])
#    pointid  lineid  pointnumber
# 0        0       0            1
# 1        1       0            2
# 2        2       0            3
# 3        3       0            4
# 4        4       1            1
# 5        5       1            2
```

[image]